# LilyPond - opacity of objects (slurs specifically)

Tags: lilypond, slurs

I am transcribing a manuscript of BWV 1011 (prelude) and there are a few slurs that appear to be a little faint:

[image: BWV 1011 prelude snippet - showing semiquavers and faint slurs]

Is there a way in which the slur opacity can be controlled in LilyPond?

Comment: I wonder *why* they are? Maybe it's a later addition? (Also: If you want to indicate this distinction in your own typeset version, it might be worth using a more noticeable method like bracketing them.)

Answer (score 4):

Lilypond currently uses a PS backend by default. PS does not support opacity, so there is no way to do so. The SVG backend will handle alpha as fourth color channel, so doing

```
{
  \override NoteHead.color = #"#000000A0"
  b'
}
```

will work with the SVG backend. Alternatively you may fake it by setting the color gray. Still, it is questionable if you really want to do so. It is quite uncommon to see transparency being used in music engraving, usually you’d go for smaller font sizes, different fonts or dashed/dotted lines for distinction.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to interpreting that measure; is that one large dashed slur, it three short slurs?

---

If you want a dashed slur, use `\slurDashed`:

```
\slurDashed
c''16( b' a' g' a' b') |
```

If you need more control of the dashes you can use `\slurDashPattern` (with a numbers for the dash ratio, and a number for the dash period):

```
\slurDashPattern #0.5 #5
c''16( b' a' g' a' b') |
```

For more options and details about dashed and dotted slurs, see:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-as-curves

---

To simply change to colour of slurs use `\override Slur.color` (and specify the colour in hexadecimal):

```
\override Slur.color = "#888888"
c''16( b') a'( g') a'( b') |
```

[image: a measure of music repeated with three different styles of slur: a single dashed slur, a single widely dash slur, and three grey slurs]